# Can gravitational waves produce "sonic boom"?

Tags: gravitational-waves, cherenkov-radiation

I've heard that a fast moving object such as a jet plane traveling much faster than speed of sound can produce shockwaves which is also known as sonic boom, also Cherenkov radiation is produce by electromagnetic waves through a medium instead. How about gravitational wave which is predicted by Albert Einstein in his paper on General Relativity, this time what can serve as a medium?

Comment: This could only happen if there is a medium in which the speed of gravity waves is slower than the speed of light. I am not aware that our observations of gravity waves are sufficiently advanced that we have observed different velocities in different media...

Comment: @Floris is there any theoretical prediction of a medium where gravity waves would be slower?

Comment: @Ruslan - I'm not aware of any. That's not the same thing as "no". I am just not the right person to answer that authoritatively.

Comment: First, I should point out that Cerenkov emission occurs because a charged particle, not an EM field, moves faster than the local speed of light in a medium.  Second, the gravitational wave itself would not produce this effect, it would be a massive particle (i.e., the analog of a charged particle in Cerenkov emission).  Third, I am not sure what the answer might be since I have no idea whether the phase speed of gravitational waves depend upon anything...

Comment: @honeste_vivere: sorry for my mistake I didn't fully understand how Cherenkov radiation works, so do you meant the charged particle outrun it's electrical field(something to do with photon) in a medium? If that's the case I'll amend my question, thanks.

Comment: @user6760 - Yes, there is some decent information at:  [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).  It's not all encompassing, of course, but it is a good starting place.